# In GCP Kubernetes (GKE) how do I assign a stateless pod created by a deployment to a provisioned vm

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

I have several operational deployments on minikube locally and am trying to deploy them on GCP with kubernetes.

When I describe a pod created by a deployment (which created a replication set that spawned the pod):

```
kubectl get po redis-sentinel-2953931510-0ngjx -o yaml
```

It indicates it landed on one of the kubernetes vms.

I'm having trouble with deployments that work separately failing due to lack of resources e.g. cpu even though I provisioned a VM above the requirements. I suspect the cluster is placing the pods on it's own nodes and running out of resources.

How should I proceed?

Do I introduce a vm to be orchestrated by kubernetes? 
Do I enlarge the kubernetes nodes?
Or something else all together?

Comment: How are you using Kubernetes with GCP?  Are you using GKE?

Comment: yes I'm using GKE after deploying it with terraform I deleted and used the UI to make sure it would work well. I have a standard 3 node cluster with 1 cpu and 3.75 memory per node.

Comment: Ok.  Then it's not quite clear what you mean by "I suspect the cluster is placing the pods on it's own nodes and running out of resources" or "introduce a vm to be orchestrated by kubernetes".  If you've configured `kubectl` to talk to your GKE cluster, then it will attempt to schedule your pods on that cluster.  If they can't be scheduled due to insufficient resource, you can increase the node-pool size via the GKE UI or CLI (or Terraform).

Comment: Can I add a vm to the pool or do I use a kubernetes node? I will read about node pools which I now know refer to cluster resources.

Comment: So far as I'm aware, the only way to managed nodes in GKE is via node pools.

Comment: Ok thanks for the lead!!!

Answer (score 0):

It was a resource problem and node pool size was inhibiting the deployments.I was mistaken in trying to provide google compute instances and disks.

I ended up provisioning Kubernetes node pools with more cpu and disk space and solved it. I also added elasticity by provisioning autoscaling.

here is a [node pool documentation](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/node-pools)

here is a [terraform Kubernetes deployment](https://github.com/google-terraform-modules/module-gcp-gke)

here is the [machine type documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/machine-types)